# How to access ForeignKey field object in order to get correct URL in views.py

Tags: python, django, url

models.py:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):

    main_menu_item = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    main_menu_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=main_menu_item)

    ...

class SubMenuItem(models.Model):

    main_menu = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items", null=True)
    sub_menu_item = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    item_page_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=sub_menu_item)
    ...
```

views.py:

```
def menus_detail(request, menu, main_menu):
    menu = get_object_or_404(SubMenuItem, item_page_slug=menu)
    main_menu = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, main_menu_slug = main_menu)

    return render(request, "menus/menus_detail.html", {"menu": menu,
                                                        "main_menu": main_menu,
                                                        })
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<slug:main_menu>/<slug:menu>", views.menus_detail, name="menus-detail"),
    ]
```

`MenuItem` and `SubMenuItem` are in one-to-many relationhip, so I am trying to copy that logic to URLs - `<slug:main_menu>/<slug:menu>`.

Currently each combination of `MenuItem` and `SubMenuItem` will work (`views.py`). I did this as a "bad" workaround solution just to see if everything else is working, but obviously it can't stay that way.

I understand that I need to access the `ForeignKey` field of `SubMenuField` inside of `views.py` in order to get the desired output. Can someone explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do extra filtering with:

```
def menus_detail(request, menu, main_menu):
    main_menu = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, main_menu_slug = main_menu)
    #           filter on the main_menu ForeignKey ↓
    menu = get_object_or_404(SubMenuItem, main_menu=main_menu, item_page_slug=menu)
    # …
```

This will thus raise a 404 if the slug for the `SubMenuItem` does not match with the slug for the `MenuItem`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I'm fine with 404 in that case. Thank you